# How do I retrieve exact input to bash from command line?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, io

How do I get bash to read input from the command line literally? I want the exact input to be preserved, so if there are quotes I want to keep them. I can accomplish what I want to do by using egrep to read from file and then sanitizing the input, like so:

```
egrep '/.*/' filename |
sed 's/\(.*\)['"'"']\(.*\) \(.*\)['"'"']\(.*\)/\1'"\'"'\2" "\3'"\'"'\4/g'
```

with "filename" containing this line

```
sed 's/foo/foo bar/g' file
```

this gives me the desired output of:

```
sed 's/foo/foo" "bar/g' file
```

Problem here is that I can't echo "$@" because bash interprets the quotes. I want the literal input without having to read from file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use ANSI-C quoting:

```
bash filename $'sed \'s/foo/foo" "bar/g\' file'
```

Note that you'd need to escape the single quotes.  This would produce:

```
sed 's/foo/foo" "bar/g' file
```

upon saying

```
echo "$@"
```

Comment: Interesting, but is there anyway to retrieve the literal input from within the script itself instead?

Comment: @JonPoler It might have helped if you had mentioned what were you trying to accomplish.

Comment: I was merely curious as to whether it is possible to accomplish the same thing internally. Thanks! I did not know about ANSI-C quoting.

Comment: After looking in to the internally parsing the arguments, I don't think it's worth the trouble. Thanks for this!